How do I track the latest UTXO when sending a transaction?
AFAIK, Cardano has data inside the UTXO, which means in order to update the data, UTXO has to be spent and the new UTXO will contain updated data, so my question is how do I keep track of latest utxo as they are thousands of transactions getting processed?
What are the techniques used to get the latest utxo?
Additionally, I want to learn more about the transaction processing so can any about kindly point out where I should look?

Do you mean the total UTxO set or just the UTxOs associated with a particular private key?

Utxo associated with the particular private key. Let suppose I want to make a change to a program and hence for state to change, the old utxo will be spent and new utxo with state will be mined. How do users keep track of the lastest utxo in this case?

Pretty sure cardano-cli can dump a text representation of all UTxO associated with a specific private key. cardano-db-sync may also be useful.

If the aim is to track the latest state change after updating the UTxO datum (for example, as in the oracle problem), then one solution is to first mint and attach an NFT to it and have that track the latest update.
